# Jenkins Error: 'Unable to Delete File' When Invoking Ant

Tags: ubuntu, ant, permissions, jenkins

I'm running Jenkins 1.433 on Ubuntu 11.04 in order to perform a build which includes an Ant task.  The `clean` portion of my Ant task, which deletes the `build` directory from prior builds, will work when running `sudo Ant` from the terminal, but fails from Jenkins with the following:

```
BUILD FAILED
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/AomaTests/build.xml:47: Unable to delete directory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/AomaTests/build
```

The Ant install referenced by Jenkins is the one which works from the command line (`usr/bin/ant`), and the Jenkins project specifically points to this instance (and not to `Default`).  Figuring this was a permissions problem, I tried the following:

- `chown -R` the appropriate `build` directory, setting its owner to `jenkins`.
- Doing a `chmod 777` on the directory.
- Temporarily allowing the `jenkins` username the ability to run things without a pasword (via editing the `sudoers` file with the line `jenkins ALL = NOPASSWD:ALL`).

None of these approaches workd.  Should I be running ant via a different user, or perhaps passing it some properties via Jenkins?

**Update**: The output of `ps -ef | grep "jenkins"` is:

```
jenkins   1647     1  0 12:28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/daemon --name=jenkins --inherit --env=JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins --output=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --pidfile=/var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid -- /usr/bin/java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/run/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=-1
jenkins   1660  1647  7 12:28 ?        00:00:13 /usr/bin/java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/run/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=-1
mattcarp  2393  2229  0 12:31 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto jenkins
```

Running `ls -l` on the directory that fails to be deleted (when run from Jenkins) shows:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins root 4096 2011-10-03 14:49 build
```

Many thanks for any advice!

Comment: Very interesting your setup. Our Jenkins workspace is in /home/jenkins and not /usr/lib/jenkins. I also don't see the job name in the directory structure. In ours, the directory would be `/home/jenkins/aromaTest/workspace/build.xml`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out, all that was required was to set the **parent** directory's owner to `jenkins`.

Wow - that was a long way to go for such a simple answer!

Comment: I'm glad you've solved the issue. The next thing I would tell you to try is to log in as Jenkins on your Jenkins server, go to the working directory, and try manually running Ant from there. This would have eliminated the fault with Jenkins. Now, knowing that Jenkins isn't in the picture, you'd look at your environment, and discovered the directory issue. The best way to resolve a build issue is to try it running the build in the workspace's directory. Just disable the job first.

Comment: What about windows? I am having the same problem in windows.. I know I have to provide admin privilege to wither jenkins or ant but how..

Answer (score 1):

Who is running Jenkins? That's the question. There is some user that's running the Java process that's running the Jenkins server. You need to find that user. Try this:

```
 $ ps -ef | grep "jenkins"
```

and see what you get.

Knowing that your name is *Matt* and I see that the file that can't be deleted is in the */home/mattcarp* directory, something tells me there's something screwy going on. My first guess is that Jenkins is not being executed by the user `mattcarp`.

- How is Jenkins installed? Is it installed as its own user in its own directory? That's usually how it is done. For example, you install Jenkins in `/home/jenkins`, and all the jobs are in `/home/jenkins/jobs`, and the workspace for a for job `foo` is in `/home/jenkins/jobs/foo/workspace`. Why is Jenkins looking at your `$HOME` directory?
- How does your Ant `build.xml` file work? Are you hard coding the directory `/home/mattcarp/workspace/...` in the `build.xml` file? If you are, you need to redo your `build.xml` to use its current directory tree and not hard code it.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I've edited my question to reflect the output of the `ps` command.  The Ant `build.xml` uses a relative path to the build directory, and Jenkins was installed using `aptitude` per the instructions on the Jenkins site.  It sits at `/var/lib/jenkins`.  I feel like I'm doing something stupid with permissions, but I'm not quite sure what...

Comment: Also, to avoid any variations, I manually moved the project files into `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace` (this is reflected in my edit to the question).  Incidentally, the output of `ps -f | grep "ant"` is: 
`mattcarp  2775  2231  0 15:41 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ant`